# Is 1/4" overlap, front door to door frame enough to prevent break-in?

Tags: security, front-door

In my Mom's gated community, there were some break-ins by robbers who stole jewelry, etc. In both cases, the robber(s) broke in the front door. The police department had a meeting with residents about preventing break-ins, and a deputy recommended having the front door reinforced, or to have it replaced with a metal door. There is 1/4 overlap, wood door on doorframe. Is that enough? I thought if you had a deadbolt, which we do, it was almost impossible to break in through the door.

Comment: A picture sure would help.

Comment: Enough for what? No residential door is break-in proof. Even deadbolts can be jimmied.

Comment: "*There is 1/4 overlap, wood door on door frame. Is that enough?*" What does that mean ? How do you think the "overlap" is a security feature ?  "*I thought if you had a deadbolt, which we do, it was almost impossible to break in through the door*."  **The dead bolt is only as strong as the wood door jamb that it is in**, easy to kick in if the plate is not secured with long screws into framing, added reinforcement is recommended. I think you need to do some research on how to make an entry door more secure. And your question should be  "How to make an entry door as secure as possible?"

Comment: @AlaskaMan, the question you suggest is highly opinion oriented and would likely get closed because of it. A better question could be "What are some options that can make an entry door more secure."

Comment: @computercarguy can you explain the difference between "*How to make an entry door as secure as possible?*" **AND** "*What are some options that can make an entry door more secure*"  What is "more" secure ? More secure than what ?

Comment: @AlaskaMan, the difference, I think, is that your version asks more about what other people would do to secure their doors, and my version asks what devices are available, without the opinion of whether it would work or not. It also avoids the "put 3 deadbolts, 2 chains, 3 slide locks, a bar across the door vertically and horizontally, and don't forget to wedge a chair under the knob" kind of "answers". And "more secure" would have to include a description of what the OP already has so there can be a baseline to compare with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as an "impossible to break in" door short of something like the NORAD facility in Colorado.  That sort of thing would be quite impractical for the average home.

The best choice, however, is a door sturdy enough to discourage the garden-variety OPPORTUNISTIC thief.  Generally they will move on if they can't get in quickly and the best thing you can do is make gaining entry difficult enough they will go somewhere else.

A steel-clad door with a steel frame is an excellent choice but you need to ensure that the frame is well anchored into the wall of the home.  A proper installation may take some construction work and if you aren't familiar with this kind of construction you should hire a qualified installer.

Keep in mind that thieves also look for other weak points to enter like windows, sliding doors, hidden keys (they know ALL the spots), etc.  So check and reinforce those as well.

Thieves like to come back to places they have hit after a few months looking for insurance-paid replacements so don't think that just because you were hit that you are in the clear.

Comment: Just watch home alone and set traps at all the weak points.  Culkin does a good job of covering them in his movie.